# JavaCC - Signal EOL Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, javacc

I've just installed JavaCC and am trying to run one of the supplied sample programs (Simple1). I have compiled it fine, but when I run it, I have a small problem. I specify the input, press enter but it does not recognise this as the end of the line.

Everywhere online I look it says 'ctrl+D' will force the program to read my input, but on my Mac it exits the program. Similarly, 'cmd+D' seems to just split the terminal window?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: The example is as follows

```
PARSER_BEGIN(Simple1)

/** Simple brace matcher. */
public class Simple1 {

  /** Main entry point. */
  public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
    Simple1 parser = new Simple1(System.in);
    parser.Input();
  }

}

PARSER_END(Simple1)

/** Root production. */
void Input() :
{}
{
  MatchedBraces() ("\n"|"\r")* <EOF>
}

/** Brace matching production. */
void MatchedBraces() :
{}
{
  "{" [ MatchedBraces() ] "}"
}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the code you are trying to compile?

Comment: It's just the Simple1.jj that comes as an example with JavaCC, it's been added to the question!

Comment: The "return" (or "enter") key will give you a newline character ("\n").  cntl-D is for EOF.

Comment: What evidence do you have the your program does not recognize the end of the line?  I'd suggest putting `"options{DEBUG_TOKEN_MANAGER="true";}` at the very start of the .jj file to get better insight. Among other things, this will tell you each character read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use cmd+D. Though this appeared to be exiting the program with no output, that was due to the nature of my code, which required EOL EOF ending, instead of just EOL or EOF.